# What are the dependencies of a FreePascal GUI app written with Lazarus?

Tags: linux, dependencies, freepascal, lazarus

I know that FreePascal apps for Linux are statically linked.  I imagine that there are some low-level APIs required.  Is this just GTK for GUI applications?  I assume a command-line app wouldn't have the same dependencies.

Where can I find a way to determine which LCL classes require which underlying APIs?

**Edit:**
Vitaly wanted to know what I found with his answer.

With a small console app:
ldd confirmed that it was a statically linked executable.
strace was more interesting.  A console-only application showed no open files.  I guess it's totally self contained.

With a simple GUI application, ldd showed some dynamic linking, and strace's output showed **many** "open"s.

It'll still take a little more research before I'm comfortable with this.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Since they are statically linked, exactly what kind of dependencies could they have?..

However you can try to work it out with a several methods...

1. `ldd <executable>` (just to be sure that your binary is not dynamically linked)
2. `strace <executable> > log.file 2&>1 && cat log.file | grep open`

> Where can I find a way to determine which LCL classes require which underlying APIs?

From my point of view, this purpose requires some hard work. I'd advice to try [systemtap](http://sourceware.org/systemtap/) for the one.

Comment: I'd played with ldd, but was unaware of strace.  I'm new to Linux development.  Thanks!

Comment: @David Crowell, please write a few words if you will manage to find the dependencies, it's interesting